# Retrofit set tag on request that gets returned with response

Tags: android, retrofit

Basically, my question is simple.  I'm using retrofit as a framework for communicating with a server which I don't control.  I want to set some sort of tag on my request which gets returned in the response automatically.  Any idea on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: refer here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886313/how-to-log-request-and-response-body-with-retrofit-android

Comment: @ethan123 what type of values are you wanting to send. You can set custom headers, but this will require the server to set the header back on the response. There are not any current request/response headers for generic data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a complex and not cool way to do this.

**0. add a tag field in your request and response type**

**1. Custom `okhttp3.RequestBody` to add a tag field:**

**2. Custom `okhttp3.ResponseBody` to add a tag field:**

**3. Custom `Converter.Factory` to set and get tag:**
for example I did some change to the `GsonResponseBodyConverter` and `GsonRequestBodyConverter`:

TagGsonRequestBodyConverter.java:

```
@Override public RequestBody convert(T value) throws IOException {
    Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(buffer.outputStream(), UTF_8);
    JsonWriter jsonWriter = gson.newJsonWriter(writer);
    adapter.write(jsonWriter, value);
    jsonWriter.close();

    TagRequestBody requestBody = TagRequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, buffer.readByteString());
    requestBody = value.tag;//just for example ,you will need to check type here
    return requestBody;
  }
```

TagGsonResponseBodyConverter.java:

```
    @Override public T convert(ResponseBody source) throws IOException {
try {
  //the ugly part,for that retrofit will wrap the responseBody with ExceptionCatchingRequestBody.(ExceptionCatchingRequestBody extends ResponseBody) 
  ResponseBody value = source;
  if (value.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ExceptionCatchingRequestBody")){
    ResponseBody temp = null;
    try {
      Field f = source.getClass().getDeclaredField("delegate");
      f.setAccessible(true);
      temp = (T) f.get(value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    value = temp != null?temp:value;
  }
  T t = adapter.fromJson(source.charStream());
  if (value instanceof TagResponseBody) {
    t.tag = ((TagResponseBody)value).tag;
  }
  return t;
} finally {
  value.close();
}
```

}

**4. add Interceptor when you create retrofit's okhttpClient,pass tag from TagRequestBody to TagResponseBody:**

```
.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                        if (request.body() instanceof TagRequestBody) {
                            TagResponseBody responseBody = new TagResponseBody(response.body());
                            responseBody.arg = ((TagRequestBody) request.body()).arg;
                            response = response.newBuilder()
                                    .body(responseBody)
                                    .build();
                        }
                        return response;
                    }
                })
```

So the tag was hold by :
RequestDataWithTag   --*CustGsonRequestBodyConverter*-->   RequestBodyWithTag   --*Interceptor*-->   ResponseBodyWithTag   --*CustGsonResponseBodyConverter*-->    ResponseDataWithTag