# Retrofit 2.x : Log Header for request and response

Tags: android, retrofit, android-networking, retrofit2

I am using retrofit 2.x and i want to log the header and body of request and response .

```
  HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .addInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("key", "value")
                            .addHeader("HEADER","HEADER Value")
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }


            }).build();
```

And this how i am doing,my problem is header of request are not being logged in Android Monitor but rest everything is logged .

Gradle Version

```
 compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3') {
    // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp peer-dependency module and define your own module import
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta3'
compile ('com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'){
    exclude module: 'okhttp'
}
```

Using RC1 and 3.0.1 due to bug issue reported [Bug Link](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1475)

Comment: Have you tried moving the logging interceptor to the last position, i. e. below the interceptor that adds he header? According to the docs: `...interceptors are called in order.` Maybe the response is just logged before the headers are added?

Comment: @david.mihola : i tried .. but it didn't work .

Comment: as an alternative, you may use facebook's stetho library http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141407/logging-in-retrofit-2-0/38890345#38890345

Answer (score 10, accepted):

May it help someone ...

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
```

Add both to see complete logs and add this interceptor at the last (don't know why but its like this).

Comment: You don't need to add both and it is basically useless. Setting `BODY` only should show all headers and bodies logs. https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.java#L132

Comment: @oldergod : Yes, I agree with you with but this what it was at 2016. :)

Answer (score 34):

Oh I found the error if anyone is interested :

```
 HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .addInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR)
        .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("key", "value")
                        .addHeader("HEADER","HEADER Value")
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }


        }).build();
```

You must add the log interceptor (your interceptor variable) after the request interceptor, so the correct answer is:

```
 HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws 
 IOException {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("key", "value")
                        .addHeader("HEADER","HEADER Value")
                        .build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }


        })
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .addInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR)
        .build();
```

Comment: Crazy that it does not state this clearly or that it's not handling all orders... Thanks! :)

Answer (score 13):

Instead of using `addInterceptor` to add the logging interceptor, use `addNetworkInterceptor`, to include headers added by OkHttp.

[Network interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) are able to:

> Observe the data just as it will be transmitted over the network.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this .

Comment: Even after this i am not able to view my custom header added to request

Comment: Using addNetworkInterceptor helped in my case. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You need to set following:

```
   OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
   HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
   httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
   clientBuilder.addNetworkInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
   clientBuilder.build()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following link was very useful:
https://medium.com/swlh/okhttp-interceptors-with-retrofit-2dcc322cc3f3

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

//Gson Builder
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());

// HttpLoggingInterceptor
HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Timber.i(message));
httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


/**
 * injection of interceptors to handle encryption and decryption
 */

//Encryption Interceptor
EncryptionInterceptor encryptionInterceptor = new EncryptionInterceptor(new EncryptionImpl());
//Decryption Interceptor
DecryptionInterceptor decryptionInterceptor = new DecryptionInterceptor(new DecryptionImpl());


// OkHttpClient. Be conscious with the order
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient()
    .newBuilder()
    //httpLogging interceptor for logging network requests
    .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
    //Encryption interceptor for encryption of request data
    .addInterceptor(encryptionInterceptor)
    // interceptor for decryption of request data
    .addInterceptor(decryptionInterceptor)
    .build();

//Retrofit
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    // for serialization
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build();

//ApiService
apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this lib if not added.

> implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2

use logger interceptor with level **Body** for all Log.

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
```

And add it to your http client. By default level is NONE.
FYI

````
enum class Level {
    /** No logs. */
    NONE,

    /**
     * Logs request and response lines.
     *
     * Example:
     * ```
     * --> POST /greeting http/1.1 (3-byte body)
     *
     * <-- 200 OK (22ms, 6-byte body)
     * ```
     */
    BASIC,

    /**
     * Logs request and response lines and their respective headers.
     *
     * Example:
     * ```
     * --> POST /greeting http/1.1
     * Host: example.com
     * Content-Type: plain/text
     * Content-Length: 3
     * --> END POST
     *
     * <-- 200 OK (22ms)
     * Content-Type: plain/text
     * Content-Length: 6
     * <-- END HTTP
     * ```
     */
    HEADERS,

    /**
     * Logs request and response lines and their respective headers and bodies (if present).
     *
     * Example:
     * ```
     * --> POST /greeting http/1.1
     * Host: example.com
     * Content-Type: plain/text
     * Content-Length: 3
     *
     * Hi?
     * --> END POST
     *
     * <-- 200 OK (22ms)
     * Content-Type: plain/text
     * Content-Length: 6
     *
     * Hello!
     * <-- END HTTP
     * ```
     */
    BODY
  }
````