# Can we print exact URL that goes to Server in AsyncHttpClient Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, asynchttpclient

I have an instance of AsyncHttpClient and i want to print the complete request that goes to the Server.

```
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
    String urlToSend = getAbsoluteUrl(url);
    client.addHeader("Authorization","Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString((BuildConfig.BASIC_AUTH_USER+":"+BuildConfig.BASIC_AUTH_PWD).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
    client.setLoggingLevel(Log.ERROR);
    client.setTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
    client.post(urlToSend, params, responseHandler);
}
```

I am able to get response and is able to see header and other stuff while debugging. But i want to print complete request made to the server in logger i.e url appended with header and body.

Comment: You can use okHttp client with interceptor, have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46535959/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar i would have used OkHttp or retrofit, but this code is of an existing product which we cannot change. Is there any way to log request using AsyncHttpClient?

Comment: I read the docs and found [this](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.html#setLoggingEnabled-boolean-) method, have a look it, hope it will help you.

Comment: No it is still printing the response but not request :-( @HemantParmar