# HttpLoggingInterceptor not logging with retrofit 2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

Im trying to log all the requests (with a network interceptor) using refrofit2, kotlin and logging-interceptor:

- retrofit: "2.0.2"
- okhttp3 : "3.2.0"
- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor 3.2.0

like:

```
val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor) // same for .addInterceptor(...)
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) //Backend is really slow
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    sRestAdapter = Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .baseUrl(if (host.endsWith("/")) host else "$host/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build()
```

It just print:

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET url...
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
```

What is happening?

--------------- EDIT --------

Errors doing requests on Main Thread are not showing by the logger, so be careful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33141407/logging-in-retrofit-2-0/38890345#38890345

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
    ...
```

you should have something like:

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
    ...
```

as the `addNetworkInterceptor()` plays with interceptors that observe a single network request and response, while `addInterceptor()` adds interceptor that observes the full span of each call: from the connection is established (if any) until after the response source is selected (either the origin server, cache, or both).

**EDIT**

> Errors doing requests on Main Thread are not showing by the logger, so be careful

Doing networking on main thread is not an "ordinary" error. It will result in your app being killed by the system with `NetworkOnMainThreadException` and this will happen before interceptor would be given any chance to run.

Answer (score 13):

```
private val interceptor = run {
    val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    httpLoggingInterceptor.apply {
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }
}


private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor) // same for .addInterceptor(...)
    .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) //Backend is really slow
    .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()
```