# How to show response errorBody in Retrofit on Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

In my app, I want to use `Retrofit2` to connect to the server and get some data.

For this, I've written the code as shown below but it doesn't show the data. And for some reason, no (detailed) error is outputted.

```java
 private void getDetailData(String auctionID, final String jwtToken) {
        showLoading(true);
        Call<DetailResponse> call = apis.getDetainAuctions(auctionID, jwtToken, agent);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<DetailResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DetailResponse> call, final Response<DetailResponse> response) {
                Log.e("detailLog", "OK");
                Log.e("detailLog", response.message() + " --- " + response.errorBody());
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DetailResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("detailLog", "Err : " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Logcat error:

```
E/detailLog:  --- okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@cbf85bc
```

What does the error mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22655234/6891563

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256827/6891563

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging with Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2)