# Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, illegalstateexception

I am developing an E-learning application. But I have a problem when parsing from JsonObject. Can you give me an easy-to-understand way to do it?

```
API request
    @GET("category")
        Observable<ResponseCategory> category(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

> {
>       "status": true,
>       "category": [
>           {
>               "category_id": "1",
>               "category_name": "Bahasa Indonesia",
>               "category_detail": null,
>               "category_thumbnail": "0"
>           },
>           {
>               "category_id": "2",
>               "category_name": "Bahasa Inggris",
>               "category_detail": null,
>               "category_thumbnail": "0"
>           },
>           {
>               "category_id": "3",
>               "category_name": "Matematika",
>               "category_detail": null,
>               "category_thumbnail": "0"
>           },
>           {
>               "category_id": "4",
>               "category_name": "IPA",
>               "category_detail": null,
>               "category_thumbnail": "0"
>           }
>       ] }

Category Model.

```
@SerializedName("category_detail")
private String mCategoryDetail;
@SerializedName("category_id")
private String mCategoryId;
@SerializedName("category_name")
private String mCategoryName;
@SerializedName("category_thumbnail")
private String mCategoryThumbnail;

public String getCategoryDetail() {
    return (String) mCategoryDetail;
}

public void setCategoryDetail(String categoryDetail) {
    mCategoryDetail = categoryDetail;
}

public String getCategoryId() {
    return mCategoryId;
}

public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
    mCategoryId = categoryId;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return mCategoryName;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    mCategoryName = categoryName;
}

public String getCategoryThumbnail() {
    return mCategoryThumbnail;
}

public void setCategoryThumbnail(String categoryThumbnail) {
    mCategoryThumbnail = categoryThumbnail;
}
```

ResponseCategory Model

```
@SerializedName("category")
private List<Category> mCategory;
@SerializedName("status")
private Boolean mStatus;

public List<Category> getCategory() {
    return mCategory;
}

public void setCategory(List<Category> category) {
    mCategory = category;
}

public Boolean getStatus() {
    return mStatus;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
    mStatus = status;
}
```

Get Response Observable from Category

```
private Observable<ResponseCategory> loadCategoryData(){
        RequestAPI requestAPI   = NetworkClient.getRetrofit().create(RequestAPI.class);

        return requestAPI.category(user.get(SessionManagement.key_token))
                .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                    handleCategoryError(throwable);
                    return null;
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

LOG HTTP REQUEST & RESPONSE

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.xxx.xxx.x/Elearning-Mobile-API/category
D/OkHttp: Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjIifQ.Ntdca3475YkDSWoiYM72FQhcJr3o8VZu6EMac-4JZZg
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.xxx.xxx.x/Elearning-Mobile-API/package/latest
D/OkHttp: Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjIifQ.Ntdca3475YkDSWoiYM72FQhcJr3o8VZu6EMac-4JZZg
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.xxx.xxx.x/Elearning-Mobile-API/package/history?user=8
D/OkHttp: Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjIifQ.Ntdca3475YkDSWoiYM72FQhcJr3o8VZu6EMac-4JZZg
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe5604240: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe5604240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe5603310)
W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
I/chatty: uid=10080(com.rakaadinugroho.msuryanusatara) identical 1 line
W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=15KB, data=30KB
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.xxx.xxx.x/Elearning-Mobile-API/category (317ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 16:08:14 GMT
D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2p PHP/7.2.10 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10
D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: ci_session=323db33987f1053c406e72a3d848f8ee; expires=Thu, 19-Dec-2019 18:08:14 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
D/OkHttp: Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 3751
D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.xxx.xxx.x/Elearning-Mobile-API/package/history?user=8 (303ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 16:08:14 GMT
D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2p PHP/7.2.10 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10
D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: ci_session=ab5cf498379d7a76bf81bb6cb1bda6a3; expires=Thu, 19-Dec-2019 18:08:14 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
D/OkHttp: Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 58
D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://192.168.122.1/Elearning-Mobile-API/package/latest (322ms)
D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2019 16:08:14 GMT
D/OkHttp: Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2p PHP/7.2.10 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10
D/OkHttp: Set-Cookie: ci_session=be900455184b37388da130a9d54ee62b; expires=Thu, 19-Dec-2019 18:08:14 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
D/OkHttp: Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 66
D/OkHttp: Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
D/OkHttp: Connection: Keep-Alive
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: {"status":true,"message":"Daftar Ujian Saya","history":[]}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (58-byte body)
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
I/chatty: uid=10080(com.rakaadinugroho.msuryanusatara) identical 1 line
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
D/OkHttp: {"status":true,"message":"Latest Examination","package_latest":[]}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (66-byte body)
I/Choreographer: Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/OkHttp: <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
D/OkHttp: <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
D/OkHttp: <p>Severity: Notice</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$detail</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Filename: controllers/Category.php</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Line Number: 26</p>
D/OkHttp:   <p>Backtrace:</p>
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/application/controllers/Category.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 26<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: _error_handler            </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 708<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: index_get         </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/index.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 315<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: require_once          </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp: </div>
D/OkHttp: <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
D/OkHttp: <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
D/OkHttp: <p>Severity: Notice</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$detail</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Filename: controllers/Category.php</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Line Number: 26</p>
D/OkHttp:   <p>Backtrace:</p>
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/application/controllers/Category.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 26<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: _error_handler            </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 708<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: index_get         </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/index.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 315<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: require_once          </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp: </div>
D/OkHttp: <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
D/OkHttp: <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
D/OkHttp: <p>Severity: Notice</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$detail</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Filename: controllers/Category.php</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Line Number: 26</p>
D/OkHttp:   <p>Backtrace:</p>
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/application/controllers/Category.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 26<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: _error_handler            </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 708<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: index_get         </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/index.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 315<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: require_once          </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp: </div>
D/OkHttp: <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">
D/OkHttp: <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
D/OkHttp: <p>Severity: Notice</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$detail</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Filename: controllers/Category.php</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Line Number: 26</p>
D/OkHttp:   <p>Backtrace:</p>
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/application/controllers/Category.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 26<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: _error_handler            </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 708<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: index_get         </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:           <p style="margin-left:10px">
D/OkHttp:           File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Elearning-Mobile-API/index.php<br />
D/OkHttp:           Line: 315<br />
D/OkHttp:           Function: require_once          </p>
D/OkHttp:       
D/OkHttp:   
D/OkHttp: </div>{"status":true,"category":[{"category_id":"1","category_name":"Bahasa Indonesia","category_detail":null,"category_thumbnail":"0"},{"category_id":"2","category_name":"Bahasa Inggris","category_detail":null,"category_thumbnail":"0"},{"category_id":"3","category_name":"Matematika","category_detail":null,"category_thumbnail":"0"},{"category_id":"4","category_name":"IPA","category_detail":null,"category_thumbnail":"0"}]}
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (3751-byte body)
```

Comment: Check this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418662/expected-begin-object-but-was-string-at-line-1-column-1#comment45170758_28418662)

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting proper json response? kindly debug and check whether you are getting proper response.

Comment: I just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your response object need to be like this.

```
public class ResponseCategory
{
    private Category[] category;

    private String status;

    public Category[] getCategory ()
    {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory (Category[] category)
    {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getStatus ()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus (String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [category = "+category+", status = "+status+"]";
    }
}


public class Category
{
    private String category_name;

    private String category_id;

    private null category_detail;

    private String category_thumbnail;

    public String getCategory_name ()
    {
        return category_name;
    }

    public void setCategory_name (String category_name)
    {
        this.category_name = category_name;
    }

    public String getCategory_id ()
    {
        return category_id;
    }

    public void setCategory_id (String category_id)
    {
        this.category_id = category_id;
    }

    public null getCategory_detail ()
    {
        return category_detail;
    }

    public void setCategory_detail (null category_detail)
    {
        this.category_detail = category_detail;
    }

    public String getCategory_thumbnail ()
    {
        return category_thumbnail;
    }

    public void setCategory_thumbnail (String category_thumbnail)
    {
        this.category_thumbnail = category_thumbnail;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [category_name = "+category_name+", category_id = "+category_id+", category_detail = "+category_detail+", category_thumbnail = "+category_thumbnail+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you log the server response here?

Comment: use this link to log server response : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886313/how-to-log-request-and-response-body-with-retrofit-android

Comment: W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
I/chatty: uid=10080(com.rakaadinugroho.msuryanusatara) identical 1 line
W/StaticLayout: maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
D/ContentValues: loadToken: 2
    loadToken: 8
    loadToken: 2

Comment: This is not what I'm expecting,  just log server response here

Comment: Based on the logs, it states that there is an error in backend side on hitting this api, check in postman.

Comment: D/OkHttp: <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
D/OkHttp: <p>Severity: Notice</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$detail</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Filename: controllers/Category.php</p>
D/OkHttp: <p>Line Number: 26</p>
D/OkHttp:   <p>Backtrace:</p>
D/OkHttp: